# Accessing Polymer dynamic elements

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

How I can access an element inside `dom-if` condition?

That's part of my template:

```
<template>
   ...
   <template is="dom-if" if="{{_displayUserLevelBadge(level)}}">
      <div class="profileUserLevelContainer">
         <iron-icon id="userLevelBadge" class="icon-20" icon="chat:verified-user"></iron-icon>
         <span class="profileUserLevel">{{userLevelString}}</span>
      </div>
   </template>
   ...
</template>
```

I need to access `#userLevelBadge` in Javascript like that:
Look in the `ready` method.

```
Polymer({
  is: 'custom-element',
    properties: {
      level: {
        type: String,
        value: null
      },
      userLevelString: {
        type: String,
        value: ''
      }
    },
    ready: function() {
      var userLevelBadge = this.$$('#userLevelBadge'); //return undefined
    },
    _displayUserLevelBadge: function(){
      //not including my code
      //Just returning true for simplicity
      return true;
    }
}
```

But it does not work. The condition is meet, and the HTML inside `dom-if` is displayed, but i can't access it using `this.$$(selector)`, as specified in the [Wiki](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom.html#node-finding).

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Fr0z3n/sntyw50u/

Comment: If the condition is true, it should work, otherwise not. If you need to access while false, you might want to use `hidden` instead.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer it should, but doesn't. Updated with fiddle.

Comment: Sounds familiar, I guess you need to give Polymer some air to breathe to stamp the `if` template by wrapping your code with `this.async()`

Comment: Thanks! I just tried and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the code in `this.async()` to give Polymer some time to stamp the template content.